# NPM install hangs on stage:loadCurrentTree

Tags: npm

I have a package on npm that links to git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/own-repository/coreee.git#release-2.0

It hangs very often. Occasionally it will install fast, but more often i must wait like idk, 15 minutes before it started. It was stuck on this line:

```
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠧ rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 353d0cde074aa46d
```

npm config list give me this:

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.9.0 node/v10.15.0 darwin x64"

; userconfig /Users/me/.npmrc
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

; node bin location = /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/node
; cwd = /Users/me/Sites/own/website
; HOME = /Users/me
```

Log of my last npm install:

```
npm i coreee --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/node',
npm verb cli '/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/npm',
npm verb cli 'i',
npm verb cli 'coreee',
npm verb cli '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@6.9.0
npm info using node@v10.15.0
npm verb npm-session f99560e8a75bc1cb
npm info lifecycle coreee@2.0.0~prepack: coreee@2.0.0
npm info lifecycle coreee@2.0.0~postpack: coreee@2.0.0
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in **656301ms** <--- WTF!
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 25ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 1529ms
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/immutable 149ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/jss 163ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/hammerjs 181ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/axios 191ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/fbemitter 202ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/calendar-js 202ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/jss-camel-case 202ms (from cache)
...

...
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/deep-diff 114ms (from cache)
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 11518ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 13695ms
npm timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 131ms
npm verb correctMkdir /Users/me/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using /Users/me/.npm/_locks/staging-63f53d125cff0e0c.lock for /Users/me/Sites/own/website/node_modules/.staging
npm timing audit submit Completed in 753ms
npm http fetch POST 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 753ms
npm timing audit body Completed in 2ms
npm timing action:extract Completed in 6750ms
npm info lifecycle coreee@2.0.0~preuninstall: coreee@2.0.0
npm info lifecycle coreee@2.0.0~uninstall: coreee@2.0.0
npm verb unbuild rmStuff coreee@2.0.0 from /Users/me/Sites/own/website/node_modules
npm info lifecycle coreee@2.0.0~postuninstall: coreee@2.0.0
npm timing action:unbuild Completed in 1ms
npm timing action:remove Completed in 144ms
npm timing action:finalize Completed in 4ms
npm timing action:refresh-package-json Completed in 6ms
npm info lifecycle coreee@2.0.0~preinstall: coreee@2.0.0
npm timing action:preinstall Completed in 0ms
npm info linkStuff coreee@2.0.0
npm timing action:build Completed in 1ms
npm info lifecycle coreee@2.0.0~install: coreee@2.0.0
npm timing action:install Completed in 1ms
npm info lifecycle coreee@2.0.0~postinstall: coreee@2.0.0
npm timing action:postinstall Completed in 0ms
npm verb unlock done using /Users/me/.npm/_locks/staging-63f53d125cff0e0c.lock for /Users/me/Sites/own/website/node_modules/.staging
npm timing stage:executeActions Completed in 6926ms
npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 677567ms
npm verb saving [ { name: 'coreee',
npm verb saving spec:
npm verb saving 'git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/own/coreee.git#release-2.0',
npm verb saving save: 'dependencies' } ]
npm verb shrinkwrap skipping write for package.json because there were no changes.
npm info lifecycle undefined~preshrinkwrap: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~shrinkwrap: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~postshrinkwrap: undefined
npm WARN react-native-gesture-handler@1.3.0 requires a peer of react-native@>= 0.58.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-apollo@2.5.6 requires a peer of apollo-client@beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ coreee@2.0.0
updated 1 package and audited 37620 packages in **678.671s** <--- WTF!
found 30 vulnerabilities (7 low, 5 moderate, 18 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 679103ms
npm info ok
```

I have done npm cache clean --force to no result.
I have deleted my package-lock.json to no result.
What could i possibly missed? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: How did you resolve this issue ? even I'm stuck with it

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, the fault is in the ISP, after we raise this issue to our Internet Service Provider, they do a net trace and fix it.

Comment: That may not be the reason in my case, because it works fine on other laptop of mine with same internet connection. Anyways thanks for the response.